Sysbench: which value should I look for fileio benchmarking
So I’m trying to conduct benchmark on various devices using sysbench. So I was wondering what I should look for
This is the code I run:
sysbench —-test=fileio —-file-total-size=100M —-file-test-mode=rndrw run
The below is the output I get. Please let me know if I should add anything else to the code that makes the analysis easier
sysbench 1.0.18 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3)
Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 1
Initializing random number generator from current time
File operations:
reads/s:                     959.09
writes/s:                    639.39
fsyncs/s:                    2764.92
Throughput:
read, MiB/s:                 14.98
written, MiB/s:              9.99
General statistics:
total time:                          10.0034s
total number of events:              15995
Latency (ms):
min:                                    0.01
avg:                                    0.62
max:                                   10.04
95th percentile:                        1.49
sum:                                 9976.31
Threads fairness:
events (avg/stddev):           15995.0000/0.00
execution time (avg/stddev):   9.9763/0.00

What are you trying to find out?  What do you mean by "fileio benchmarking"?

@AndrewL - file I/O benchmark is used to measure and test the performance of a system's storage subsystem, such as hard drives, SSDs, or other storage devices.
